# Why does javascript indexOf() method throw error when called from C# code-behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using Google Navigation charts in a project.

Everything works fine when I run the javascript code in the client side (.aspx page), but when I put it in the code behind and echo/write it out (via Response.Write()) it throws an error, specifically at the point where the javascript code trys to call the indexOf() method on an array.

I have tried to examine the cause of the error, but the only info I get is that this is a problem in IE8 and earlier with the indexOf() method- this cannot be my problem, because as I said it works fine when I call it directly from the client - it is only giving a problem form the code-behind.

This is the specific error I receive:

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'

This will work fine (in client):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns() ; i++) {
if (i == 0 || defaultSeries.indexOf(i) > -1) {
// if the column is the domain column or in the default list, display the series
columns.push(i);
}
....
```

but this will throw an error (in code-behind):

```
htmlJS += "for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns() ; i++) {";
htmlJS += "if (i == 0 || defaultSeries.indexOf(i) > -1) {";
// if the column is the domain column or in the default li";st, display the series
htmlJS += "columns.push(i);";
htmlJS += "}";
....
Response.Write(htmlJS);
```

Does anyone know why this error only occurs from the code-behind?

Comment: There must be some other difference. As you say there is no Array.indexOf() in IE8.

Comment: What is `defaultSeries`? Is it a string or an array? What are its typical contents?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `defaultSeries` is an array, you **will** need to polyfill `Array.prototype.indexOf` for IE<9, which only supports indexOf on strings.

Here's a [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
  if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement, fromIndex) {
      if ( this === undefined || this === null ) {
        throw new TypeError( '"this" is null or not defined' );
      }

      var length = this.length >>> 0; // Hack to convert object.length to a UInt32

      fromIndex = +fromIndex || 0;

      if (Math.abs(fromIndex) === Infinity) {
        fromIndex = 0;
      }

      if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex += length;
        if (fromIndex < 0) {
          fromIndex = 0;
        }
      }

      for (;fromIndex < length; fromIndex++) {
        if (this[fromIndex] === searchElement) {
          return fromIndex;
        }
      }

      return -1;
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Based on your code, you might have a white-space issue with the javascript - you are concatenating the string, and so, for example, you will have a section that looks like "{if" - however, this is not likely causing your issue.
2. What IS likely causing your issue is the timing of the javascript hitting the page.  Does the object EXIST when the response.write gets flushed to the client?  In order to make sure that all the required bits of the page exist when you need them, you normally will want to use the scripting object methods to add the script, and then CALL the code on once the page is loaded.  Check out this page on adding script dynamically to a page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone - I have found a soltuion that works:

If I create the same string which contains the javascript indexOf() method and then either assign it as output to a literal element on the aspx page, or if I "echo" it out via the <% %> special tags then the javascript code will run fine.

So the following runs:

Code-Behind:

```
public string jsHtml ="";

jsHtml +="<script type='text/javascript'>";
jsHtml+="var defaultSeries = [1,2,3];";
jsHtml+="alert(defaultSeries.indexOf(2));";
jsHtml+="</script>";

txtValueA.Text = jsHtml;
```

Client/aspx page:

```
<asp:Literal ID="txtValueA" runat="server></asp:Literal>
//OR
<%=jsHtml %>
```

Strange but True..... thanks for the input